# Replace linear Compact Flourescent bulb with 2 pin

Tags: bathroom

Does anyone knows how to replace a linear CFL bulb that cannot be twisted? I tried pulling it out but failed.Thank you. I [image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to pull that little tab out on the socket with a small screwdriver or knife. This will "unlock" the bulb assembly and then you can pull it out of the socket.

Comment: Make sure the power is off before you go sticking sharp metal objects into a light bulb socket.

Comment: But that takes all the fun out of it, @MosheKatz!